# why is there a net current at halfwave potential?

Tags: electrochemistry

Im wondering why there is a current measured at a halfwave potential? According to my understanding at the halfwave potential of a diffusion controlled reduction or oxiation at an electrode, there is half of the current due to anodic and the other half of the current due to cathodic current. I assume that therefore the net current is zero, since the same amount of electrons/charge leaves and enters the electrode...

Comment: You have it all backwards. Not half, but ***all*** current is due to anodic half-reaction. Also, all of it is due to cathodic half-reaction. Each single electron participates in both.

Comment: I guess I do not really understand...
I expect that we are just observing the working electrode, right?
and here a reduction or oxidation can occur, resulting in cathodic or anodic current, respectively. is this correct?
So how is it possible that all current is anodic and cathodic at same moment in time?